# Can telekinetics in Stranger Things such as Vecna be killed physically or only psychically?

Tags: stranger-things

In *Stranger Things*, there are numerous psychics. Eleven, Kali, Vecna, and the other test subjects are such examples. Normally they are fought or killed by other telekinetic forces.

My question is specifically regarding Vecna, but in the context of all of Dr. Brenner's test subjects.

Telekinetic individuals do not seem to have extra physical protections, except for Vecna. Therefore, it would seem that they could be killed with a simple bullet, or even more archaically a machete. Vecna is the exception, but assuming he only has enhanced durability and is not actually immortal like the Vecna in DnD, he should be able to be killed through more forceful weapons, like a nuke or decapitation.

Could Vecna, and the other test subjects, be killed through ordinary (physical) means, or is there some kind of trick or special method/instruction needed to do so?

Comment: I don't see why not. The question is whether pain would be as much of a distraction or limiting influence on him as it would be for another; chop somebody's arm off, and they're likely to stop attacking you (or at least stop attacking you as effectively). Similarly, it's possible he has some enhanced healing abilities (he was burned, but apparently recovered though with massive scarring), but that doesn't necessarily mean he has Wolverine-level ability to recover from physical trauma.

Answer (score 3):

### We largely do not know (but there are some clues)

**In the case of Vecna**, it seems clear that he cannot be (easily) killed by physical force, nor indeed easily killed by psychic powers! Indeed, in the fight at the end of Season 4, Vecna is set on fire and shot multiple times before falling out a window; Eleven, however, suggests that he survived this damage:

> ELEVEN: Now that I'm here, in Hawkins, I can feel him. And he's hurt. He's
> hurting. But he's still alive.
>
> "Chapter Nine: The Piggyback"

More than that, he seems to have recovered enough to make a rapid getaway within under a minute of suffering this serious damage to his body.

Recall also that Eleven *partly disintegrated* him while pushing him into the Upside-Down (as she successfully did later with the Demogorgon), after which he looked like this:

[image: A half-disintegrated Vecna is visible as Eleven opens a portal to the Upside-Down behind him.]

However, before being hit by the supernatural energies of the Upside-Down, he looked like this, suggesting that he may have been able to pull himself back together even before his transformation or corruption by the Upside-Down.

[image: Vecna, before his transformation, falls through the Upside-Down lit by red lightning.]

We also know that his consciousness extends far beyond his body, through the Mind Flayer, the Demogorgons, and so forth. There is nothing in the previous to say that decapitation or  complete incineration of his body, such as by a nearby nuclear explosion, would *not* be effective, but it is suggestive.

**In the case of Eleven**, many of her powers are similar to Vecna's, and she is perhaps more powerful than Vecna was before he entered the Upside-Down, since she did get the better of him and has only had time to practice since then. She *has* been shown to be susceptible to mundane forms of subdual (drugs and so forth) and to physical injury, but then again, no one has inflicted a nearly-lethal injury on her, so we do not know if killing her would work normally, or if it might, say, reduce her to a disembodied consciousness. Still, on the balance of evidence, Eleven could probably be killed normally: we have never seen her exhibit any type of supernatural resistance to injury, but we have seen her injured normally various times.

**In the case of the other psychics**, there is really nothing to suggest that they have any abnormal resistance to physical harm, particularly since the rest of the psychokinetic subjects were far weaker than Eleven or Vecna. However, while Vecna may seem to have killed them with brute force, we know that his method of killing people also seems to involve taking their souls, or something along those lines:

> VECNA: With each life I took, I grew stronger. More powerful. They were
> becoming a part of me.
>
> "Chapter Seven: The Massacre at Hawkins Lab"

Since he did kill them with something more than mere brute force, we cannot entirely rule out that the other test subjects are also difficult to kill by normal means. Again, however, there is nothing to suggest it.

---

As a side note, it is worth mentioning that any of the powerful psychics—Vecna and Eleven, at the very least— might, with sufficient practice, have means of protecting themselves from weapons such as bullets and machetes, since they could probably channel their telekinesis to deflect these weapons.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have specifically mentioned Vecna, I will like to point out how Henry Creel was kept under control for years through the help of Soteria, the chip that was implanted in Henry's neck.

Soteria is a miniature device that, when implanted into the neck of an individual with psychokinetic abilities, inhibits that person's abilities.

So it can be assumed that other psychics too could be rendered powerless through the help of this chip and after you have successfully implanted the chip in the individuals neck, just shoot him,nuke him, or decapitate them they will die like anyone else.

STEPS to kill a psychic -  1. Identify and locate Psychic individual.

2. Obtain and implant Soteria into the individuals neck
3. Say a cool one liner ( Hasta La Vista Baby is highly advised)
4. Shoot, nuke or decapitate your preferred psychic with a weapon of your choice.